# After import a mysqldump can't access to MySQL with root or any created user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant

**Background:** I use vagrant (Ubuntu 18.04) to create my development environment,I'm install PHP, MySQL and other stuff but recently I got the problem that I can access to mysql and then I got the classic error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

using `sudo mysql` or

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'otheruser'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

when trying `mysql -u otheruser -p`

The problems is that MySQL is working fine for a fews 'vagrant up' and 'vagrant halt' but for some reason when I start the box again I can't access to MySQL anymore. I know that I can reset the MySQL root password, remove MySQL or do another quick solution, but most of all I want to know **what is the cause of the problem** because at first I was thinking about something related to an update I done to my vagrant box, or an update on Ubuntu.

When I install mysql on that Box with Ubuntu I use a .sh file to automate the process, here is the section of mysql:

```
# Mysql Instalation
sudo apt install mysql-server -y
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysql < setup.sql
```

and the setup.sql :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'rootpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER 'otheruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'otherpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'otheruser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I tried to figure out what the problem and tried to resolve it, first I commented the lines of the root statement on the setup.sql file and then later commenting the 'mysql_secure_installation' line on the .sh file but the problems persists; so to solve quickly I destroy the box and then I create it again, but this turned boring at this point, so here I'm here to describe my problem.

so resuming the questions are:

- What could be the cause of the problem?, so I can resolve it on future box creations.
- What is the best way to solve this kind of problem.

Because it is overwhelming create and destroy the box every time the problem occurs and most important when I move an app to a production server I don't want this kind of problems.

Thanks for your time reading this. Have a nice day.

**Update 06/Feb/2020**

After review my deploy process to find more information about the problem I find out that the problem starts when I do an import from a mysqldump
from my production server; just after the import and do a `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` again the problem occurs so Im unable to login on MySQL again.

Here is my mysqldump process and my import process to help is there is something wrong.

**Production Server with Ubuntu 16.04 MySQL 5.7.29**

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb_04-02-2020.sql`

**Vagrant Box with Ubuntu 18.04 MySQL 5.7.29**

`mysql -u otheruser -p < alldb_04-02-2020.sql`

Comment: I had an issue previously where I had messed up a Vagrant config file such that mysql didn't start on boot. Perhaps you have already done this, but have you tried verifying that mysql is running when you cannot access it? `sudo service mysql status`

Comment: @Leif_Lundberg yeah already tried that, but it is curious how this happens

Answer (score 0):

On your Dev server, `setup.sql` changes `root@localhost` and adds `otheruser@localhost` account. Information about users is stored in `mysql.user` grants table. You're using `--all-databases` option when creating dump of your Production server. `mysql` is a system database that will be exported and it includes `mysql.user` table. Once you import this dump file, your original `mysql.user` table will be replaced with the one from the Production server. This means that users and privileges set by `setup.sql` will be replaced with users from Production server and I bet they don't include `root@localhost` and `otheruser@localhost` (you can check that with `select host, user from mysql.user;`). That's why you're not able to use these users to login to the Dev server afterwards.